# Js  не отправляет позиции обработчику помогите решить проблему!

Tags: html, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть страница редактирования контента, где есть желание реализовать возможность изменить позиции продуктов налету, перемещая строки таблицы выше или ниже. Помогите решить проблему почему-то js не оправляет позиции полей в обработчик - что не так?

Код пример: http://jsfiddle.net/upxFk/

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: а еще сделать пример кода на http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: сделал ссылку на пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

строка 11 в javascript - запятая вместо точки с запятой (перед updateIndex = function(e, ui) {)
возможно из-за этого

PS перед updateIndex = function(e, ui) { неплохо было бы var поставить

Comment: исправил, но все равно не отправляет данные или у меня php файл неправильно написан 

код php: 

        $cat_pos = str_replace("undefined", "", $_POST['posid']);
        $cat_pos1 = str_replace(";", "", $cat_pos);
        $pos = str_replace("", "", $_POST['pos']);
        $id = str_replace("", "", $_POST['id']);
        $id1 = str_replace("undefined", "", $id);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE `products` SET `pos` = '$pos[$i]' WHERE `id` = '$id1[$i]' LIMIT 1;") or die(mysql_error());
        }

Comment: нет возможности запустить ваш скрипт, убедитесь в чем проблема - в консоли браузера (Chrome, Mozilla) включите отображение ajax (XMLHttpRequests) запросов, если уходят, то беритесь за php часть, замените источник данных с $_POST на $_GET и попробуйте обратиться к этому скрипту из браузера - http://путь_к_скрипту?postid=10&pos=2&id=33 (только используйте реальные данные, которые есть у вас в базе данных) - распечатывайте все получившиеся переменные перед отправкой в БД, посмотрите это ли вы ожидаете там увидеть или нет. Шагов для простого дебага данной ситуации как видите совсем немного